# Sorting file in a directory with format page-0.ext and getting first file

Tags: python, python-2.7

In a directory full of files with format basename-{0-padded-index}.ext, how can I get these in sorted orders. Example filenames:

```
b3a7c672b9a34da68c4caab04f758cd2-000.png
b3a7c672b9a34da68c4caab04f758cd2-001.png
b3a7c672b9a34da68c4caab04f758cd2-002.png
...
b3a7c672b9a34da68c4caab04f758cd2-010.png
b3a7c672b9a34da68c4caab04f758cd2-011.png
...
b3a7c672b9a34da68c4caab04f758cd2-099.png
b3a7c672b9a34da68c4caab04f758cd2-100.png
```

0 padded index (001, 002, 010 etc) are not fixed. It can be 2 digit or more zero padded.
Once sorted, I can get the first file which is the real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

filenames = os.listdir('path/to/directory')
filenames.sort(key=lambda s: int(s.rsplit('.', 1)[0].rsplit('-', 1)[1]))
first_one = filenames[0]
```

The real trick here is the key function in `sort`, which gets the relevant part of the filename and turns it into an `int`. Therefore, all filenames will be sorted by those numbers just before the file extension

Comment: great. let me check it.